# Spring form select options

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my JSP have this fragment

```
<sf:select multiple="true" path="author" id="authors" size="7" >
  <sf:options items="${authors}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="surname"/>
</sf:select>
```

where `${authors}` is `List` with Authors objects from DB. `Author` have property `name` and `surname`.
By change `itemLabel=` in JSP i can show only `name` or `surname` of Author in list.

How can i show `name` **and** `surname` in one string in list of options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a getDisplayName() in your Author class, and reference it via displayName in your form

```
public String getDisplayName() {
    return name + " " + surname;
}
```

Assuming "name" is forename, of course...

Comment: It's work, but i think it's trick, maybe have another, correct way?

Comment: Personal preference I guess. I prefer to avoid excessive use of JSP expressions, they are harder to debug and the compiler doesn't pick up errors.  You can also add logic to your display name more easily, e.g. for where forename doesn't exist (empty or null), or where you prefer to go for something like "Smith, John (Mr)" rather than "John Smith"

Answer (score 1):

Include this jstl tag in your jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and then if you want to display drop down option as say, Name - Surname:

```
    <c:forEach items="${authors}" var="author">
        <sf:option  value="${author.name}">
            <c:out value="${author.name}"/> - <c:out value="${author.surname}"/>
        </sf:option>                     
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this by using c:forEach to populate each option in dropdown.

see below

```
<sf:select multiple="true" path="author" id="authors" size="7" >
 <c:forEach items="${authors}" var="author">
  <sf:options itemValue="author.name" itemLabel="author.surname"/>
</c:forEach>
</sf:select>
```

let me know for any further clarifications...